# I want to view a particular user information from database. But i recieve this error

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_GET['view_id']) && !empty($_GET['view_id'])){$id = $_GET['view_id'];

$stmt_edit = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT date_of_birth, phone_number,hostel_address, name_of_sponsors,phone_number_of_sponsors, gender,department, first_name, last_name, user_email, user_name, user_pass, FROM `100`WHERE user_id =:uid');
$stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
$edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
extract($edit_row);}else{
header("Location: index.php");}
```

It shows me these errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `100` WHERE user_id ='19'' at line 3' in C:\wamp\www\registration\admin\levels\100level\view.php on line 15
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `100` WHERE user_id ='19''

Comment: I don't know if a trailing comma is acceptable in the list of fields. Also, is your table really named `100`?

Comment: Digits are OK @j as long as they are back ticked.

Answer (score 1):

You have more "," after user_pass that caused SQL Syntax Error, your query must be :

```
SELECT date_of_birth, phone_number,hostel_address, name_of_sponsors,phone_number_of_sponsors, gender,department, first_name, last_name, user_email, user_name, user_pass FROM `100` WHERE user_id =:uid
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me